# How to change "\t" length in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I want to change default width of tab in `UILabel` using attributed string. How can I achieve that? I assume that I should add attribute `NSMutableParagraphStyle`, but I don't know which property is responsible for tab length.

Let's use this code for example:

```
let text = "test\ttest"
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: textRange)
```

Comment: How many spaces are you trying to add?

Comment: Let's say I want around 8 points space, if I add e.g. "  " the problem is with coloring text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle), `var tabStops: [NSTextTab]!` is an array of `NSTextTab` objects representing the receiver’s tab stops. You can access tabs and change their location as follows:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: newTabLength, options: [:])]

label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
```

Comment: This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

To change the length of the tabstops via `NSMutableParagraphStyle` you have to create a new array of `NSTextTab` instances and assign it to the `tabStops` array

```
let text = "test\ttest\ttest"
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
let tabInterval : CGFloat = 40.0
var tabs = [NSTextTab]()
for i in 1...10 { tabs.append(NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: tabInterval * CGFloat(i))) }
paragraphStyle.tabStops = tabs
let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: textRange)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately @Dorukhan Arslan wast first, I will accept his answer.

Comment: @ThirdMartian No problem 

Comment: Note that I showed a way of changing length of tab character in an attributed text only for the first tab in my answer. @vadian's answer provides a good extension to apply it for following tabs as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can try replacing the \t with number of space you want

```
var text = "test\ttest"
text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\t", with: " ")
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: textRange)
```

Comment: Adding few " " results the same if I would add one space.